# Accessing by direct URL keeping locale in session in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, localization

I have a problem with my URLs.

I have a posting-news function in my website. I have used Voyager CMS for this. And my webiste has 3 languages('ru' , 'en' , 'uz'). Actually I can add news in three languages.
Some news are added only in one language. Two others is emypty.

And my direct URL for actual article look like this https://mywebsite.uz/hcont/562 .

For example, the language of the website is english by default. I have added new post in russian only(english and uzbek is empty). When someone access to newly added post by direct URL https://mywebsite.uz/hcont/562 like this. It shows empty page. Because website loads default language(if you entering website first time).
I want to change locale by clicking direct URL.

I know that firstly, I have to make route https://mywebsite.uz/news/562/en like this.
The question is how should I configure this URL in middleware,controller and route?

Below my code which working right now for https://mywebsite.uz/hcont/562 :

## web.php

```
Route::resource('hcont','HomeController');

Route::get("locale/{locale}" , function($locale){
    Session::put('locale',$locale);
    
    return redirect()->back();
});
```

## HomeController.php

```
 public function show($id){
        $data = News::findOrFail($id);
        $data->load('translations');
        return view('the-news' , compact('data' ,'locale'));
    }
```

## home.blade.php

```
              @foreach($news as $item)
                <a href="{{ route('hcont.show', $item->id) }}">
                  <div class="news-item">
                    <div>
                       <img src="{{Voyager::image($item->img)}}" alt="">
                         <div class="news-content">
                          <h5>{!!$item->getTranslatedAttribute('title', \App::getLocale(), 'ru')!!}</h5>
                          <p>{!!str_limit($item->getTranslatedAttribute('body', \App::getLocale(), 'ru') , 70)!!}</p>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              @endforeach
```

## Localization.php

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if(\Session::has('locale')){
            \App::setLocale(\Session::get('locale'));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [Voyager is not a CMS](https://voyager.readme.io/docs/what-is-voyager). You should probably actually use a CMS for this kind of things.

One way to do what you are trying to achieve is, accepting the `locale` as part of the URL as an optional parameter (ending with `?`), and with required validation.

```
Route::get('/{id}/{locale?}', 'HomeController@show');
```

Then inside the `HomeController` you can decide which locale to load

```
public function show($id, $locale = 'en')
{
        $data = News::findOrFail($id);

        return view('the-news' , compact('data' ,'locale'));
}
```

This way, `en` acts as a default locale (for URLs without any locale specified) but if a locale is given via the URL, you can process that accordingly.